# Python deleting a block of lines from a file

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm struggling to figure out as to how I should go about deleting a block of lines from a file. Below is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import re
import string

##getting user inputs
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')  
args = p.parse_args()
kkk_list = args.input


def printInFormat(ip, port, name):
    formattedText = '''HOST Address:{ip}:PORT:{port} 
                        mode tcp 
                        bind {ip}:{port} name {name}'''.format(ip=ip, 
                                                                port=port, 
                                                                name=name)
    textWithoutExtraWhitespaces =  '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in formattedText.splitlines()])
    # you can break above thing
    # text = ""
    # for line in formattedText.splitlines():
    #       text += line.strip()
    #       text += "\n" 

    return(formattedText)

#####here im writing writing the user inoput to a file and it works great.
#with open("file.txt", "a") as myfile:
#    for kkk in kkk_list:
#         ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
#         myfile.write(printInFormat(ip, port, name))

###### here is where im struggling. 
for kkk in kkk_list:
    ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
    tobedel = printInFormat(ip, port, name)  
    f = open("file.txt", "r+")
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    if kkk != "tobedel":
        f.write(YY)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

As you can see I'm appending the file.txt with user inputs. i.e (format:ip:port:name). File will contain below entries when the script is excuted as ./script.py 192.168.0.10:80:string 192.168.0.10:80:string

```
Host Address:192.168.0.10:PORT:80
mode tcp
bind 192.168.0.10:80 abc    
Host Address:10.1.1.10:PORT:443
mode tcp
bind 10.1.1.10:443 xyz
```

Now I want to delete the line(s) from file.txt when the user input is given the same way. With the above code being run nothing happens. I'm a beginner and really appreiciate if you help me understand. This question is related to [python multiple user args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512392/python-multiple-user-arguments-to-a-list)

Comment: You want to delete what? can you explain a bit. May be with the same example. It is not really clear from your code.

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm trying to delete those 2 blocks mentioned in the second code window. When the script is run with args <ip>:<port>:<name> it should  delete the corresponding entries from file.txt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me point out the little things you are missing.

```
for kkk in kkk_list:
    ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
    tobedel = printInFormat(ip, port, name)  
    f = open("file.txt", "r+")
    d = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    if kkk != "tobedel":
        f.write(YY)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

1. You opened the file inside the loop and closing outside. The file object is out of scope. Use `with` which handles the context automatically for you.
2. It is a bad idea to open a file inside a loop, because it will create so many file descriptor which consumes a lot of resources.
3. You never mentioned what is `YY` when you are writing.
4. You can delete lines here as you are trying to delete multiple lines in one go, so `d = f.readlines()` should be `d = f.read()`

Below is the updated the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
import re
import string

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')  
args = p.parse_args()
kkk_list = args.input # ['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']


def getStringInFormat(ip, port, name):
    formattedText = "HOST Address:{ip}:PORT:{port}\n"\
                    "mode tcp\n"\
                    "bind {ip}:{port} name {name}\n\n".format(ip=ip, 
                                                                port=port, 
                                                                name=name)

    return formattedText

# Writing the content in the file
# with open("file.txt", "a") as myfile:
#    for kkk in kkk_list:
#         ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
#         myfile.write(getStringInFormat(ip, port, name))



with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()

    # below two lines delete old content of file
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()

    # get the string you want to delete
    # and update the content
    for kkk in kkk_list:
        ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)

        # get the string which needs to be deleted from the file
        stringNeedsToBeDeleted = getStringInFormat(ip, port, name)

        # remove this from the file content    
        fileContent = fileContent.replace(stringNeedsToBeDeleted, "")

    # delete the old content and write back with updated one
    # f.truncate(0)
    f.write(fileContent)

# Before running the script file.txt contains 

# HOST Address:192.168.1.10:PORT:80
# mode tcp
# bind 192.168.1.10:80 name name1
#
# HOST Address:172.25.16.2:PORT:100
# mode tcp
# bind 172.25.16.2:100 name name3

# After running file.txt will be empty
# as we have deleted both the entries.
```

Comment: thanks so much. can you check the code again for me please cos it doesnt delete the 3 lines or anything at all from the file when the script is run as "./del.py 192.168.0.10:80:somename1". I have the lines Host Address:192.168.0.10:PORT:80/mode tcp/bind 192.168.0.10:80 somename1. kindly note "/" corresponds to a new line cos this window doesnt let me use enter key. Please help out rahul I think we are very very close.

Comment: @bindo use above code, it will work. The previous code you had have some spaces and tabs and I fixed it in above code. It is working I checked it again.

Comment: Thanks so much rahul, you really are a genius. I just tried the code and its working perfectly. The way you've addressed the problem is excellent where you've specified all the lines in a variable instead of stressing over complex regex patterns. I fiddled with the code a little to search and delete lines with tabs, so far no issues.

Comment: Thank you. Regex would be better but you can try it later on. Also, if you like the answer please upvote the it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways do it. I tried to create a new file leaving all the blocks. You can drop the old file and rename the new file as old file.
Following is the working code for same.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import argparse
 import re
 import string

##getting user inputs
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", help="input the data in format ip:port:name", nargs='*')  
args = p.parse_args()
kkk_list = args.input # ['192.168.1.10:80:name1', '172.25.16.2:100:name3']



# returns the next block from the available file. Every block contains 3 lines as per definition.
def getNextBlock(lines, blockIndex):
    if len(lines) >= ((blockIndex+1)*3):
        line = lines[blockIndex*3]
        line += lines[blockIndex*3+1]
        line += lines[blockIndex*3+2]
    else:
        line = ''

    return line

# file  - holds reference to existing file of all blocks. For efficiency keep the entire content in memory (lines variable)
file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
linesCount = len(lines)

# newFile holds reference to newly created file and it will have the resultant blocks after filtering
newFile = open("file_temp.txt","w")


# loop through all inputs and create a dictionary of all blocks to delete. This is done to have efficiency while removing the blocks with O(n) time

delDict = {}
for kkk in kkk_list:
    ip, port, name = re.split(":|,", kkk)
    tobedel = printInFormat(ip, port, name)
    delDict[tobedel] = 1

for i in range(linesCount / 3):
    block = getNextBlock(lines, i)
    if block in delDict:
        print 'Deleting ... '+block
    else:
        #write into new file
        newFile.write(block)

file.close()
newFile.close()

#You can drop the old file and rename the new file as old file
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. If you do not mind  can you please include comments from def getNextBlock? My primary objective is to learn and it will be really helpful.

Comment: Makes much more sense now. Thanks a lot. I will test this out again